# Unknown String value Translations to Other Languages WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, language-translation

In my app, I will retrieve, lets say 3 items/fields. field1, field2, field3. At this point I dont know what their values are.

Only after the retrieval of these fields at runtime will the values be known.

How should I go about translating these values into a different language. Lets say just portuguese for now.

All the fields are string.
These fields will be displayed in TextBlocks in the xaml file.

Question: How do I go about doing this? All samples I found online are all using resx files that have known values.

Links will also help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had the same issue, and solved it using resources file "RESX" and converters, if you want to use resx file tell me to post you the correct code that does that.

Comment: To use a resx file, wouldn't the values be known?

Comment: resx files will be used as a dictionary, you have to define words or phrases and their translations, otherwise, how do you want to do to translate unknown words? using Google translation API for example?

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/translate/v2?hl=FR if you want to use it, you have to use ValueConverter also.

Comment: Those are some options, but some links online say that Google translator and Bing translator don't work anymore without paying or registering your app.

Comment: that link states that a AppKey is required. To get that you have to register your app. I dont want to do that

Comment: With bing translator, they said: "up to 2 million characters a month, are free. Translating more than 2 million characters per month requires a payment." take a look here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to take the cheap way out. I created resource dictionaries with lists of possible values for selected languages(Since the values that will be entered are more or less predictable). I then just loop through the dictionaries to find the value of the current language (ie English - Name(value)) then get the Key and use that to loop through the other dictionary for the desired languages value.

Its a big workaround but it gave me less trouble than when I used google translate.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

Edit:

---

When I say loop through, I used foreach loops to loop through one dictionary, get the value and key and use that to loop through the second dictionary. I stated resource dictionaries but what I meant was normal dictionaries in c# coding

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you require.

First one is that you built a custom language converter class library, this is a long winded process and a lot of coding is required.

The Second one is using Google API. Below are links to use Google API for converting:
[Google API Example 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/644753/Language-Translator-Using-Google-Translate)

[Google API Example 2](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/64790-c-translator-using-google-api/)

Comment: Did you read our discussion above? he need a free API and Google translate API is not!